# Nginx error memory

Tags: nginx, php, memory, php-fpm

I have a  problem with Nginx + PHP. This is error

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 896464024 bytes) in /sistemas/html/producao_11003/prod/third/zipfile/zipfile.php on line 122" while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, request: "POST /11003/BackupProcess/BackupProcess.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.", referrer: "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/11003/gerarBackup/gerarBackup.php"
```

I tried increase memory_limit in php.ini 'cos in my info.php work, but when I run again the command I get the same error.

In my php-fpm this line have comment

```
;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128MB.
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to create a zip file inside PHP. Don't do that for a large backup file, PHP is not optimized for that. You'd be better using an external program for that. Use internal zip functions or modules for creating small (less than 10MB) zip files.

Comment: In fact, this file is big, around 1.8G.

Comment: Find a better way to do the operations you need. I would assume you would need at least 4 gigabytes memory for the process to work on a 1.8 GB file, since it is likely that both the original file and result file would be in memory. It might also be that PHP has some kind of internal limit on how much memory can use for a single worker. At least 4 GB is 2^32, which is a common limit in many places.

Answer (score 1):

All you need in the log:

```
Allowed memory ... 2147483648 bytes ... tried to allocate 896464024 bytes
```

It means that you set the value 2GB, and the application wants more(900Mb). If **you are sure that there is no memory leak** and the application really needs to use such a large amount, then there is only one way: You should increase the value **memory_limit**. But! **You'd better be aware of what's happening inside the application**.

gerarBackup.php and zipfile.php... It seems your application tried to process a big file. So, this error is expected.

Comment: Thanks, I increasing memory in php.ini up to more than 3G and check it in info.php via browser, but still get the same error.

Comment: As I said: your application tried to process a huge file. I thkink it's some kind of backup system. And it got error because there is no enough memory.

Comment: In fact, this file is big, around 1.8G.

Answer (score -1):

Increase your memory limit to 10 gb in `php.ini`. Restart `nginx` and `php-fpm`.